# How to provide callbacks to each animation within a Parallel call

Tags: react-native

Start method takes a callback to be run when the animation is done.  But, if I have multiple animations within a Parallel call and each executes over a different duration, with one start() call on the outer Animated.Parallel() call, how do I provide individual callbacks for each animation within?

```
Animated.parallel([
  Animated.timing(
    this.pos,
    {
      toValue: { x: 146, y: 10 },
      duration: 1500,
      easing: Easing.ease
    }
  ),  // I want to run a different callback here
  Animated.timing(
    this.pos2,
    {
      toValue: { x: 146, y: 10 },
      duration: 2500,
      easing: Easing.quad
    }
  ),   //  ...and here
]).start(function () {
   // code for execution after both animations are finished.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished what I wanted by using a sequence within the parallel call.